# Troubling an Issue with Auto filling up the Web form via Macro (VBA)

Tags: html, excel, vba, web

I am working on Auto web form filling , But get stuck when my code is not Working on the web page where I want to fill up the data.

But currently my code is working on other websites. I don't know why its not working there. And where I am doing this, is running on LF server.

```
Public Sub Getdata()
Dim ie As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")



ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate "http://eforms.company_name.com/lfserver/E2844_Proposal_Summary" '(example URL)


Do

DoEvents

Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4


ie.document.getElementById("bid_manager_name").Value = "samplename"

ie.document.getElementById("bid_manager_id").Value = "sampleid"

End Sub
```

[sample html - image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c0cy.png)

[When I am changing my id - "bid_manager_name" - image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LMcO.png)

I won't be able share the internal link, where I actually working. But any guess would be helpful, and why its not working. If you required any web side (html) of information them please ask me, i will try to provide you. Thanks in advance.

```
<input name="bid_manager_name" tabindex="43" title="Bid Manager name" class="transparentTxtEntry" id="bid_manager_name" style="margin: 0in; border: 1px solid rgb(177, 177, 177); left: 237%; top: 122%; width: 335%; height: 20%; text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.11; font-family: Arial; font-size: 100%; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 29; background-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: 1. Your question is hard to answer without additional information.  2. There are sites that are using special techniques to avoid automatic filling of forms, that might be the case here. Sometimes there are workarounds (but for that see 1.).

Comment: Any specific thing if you required to see, I can share the html codes, But accessing that internal URL not possible. You know !!

Comment: add a HTML snippet to the question, it might help

Comment: What does not working mean please? Is there an error? Which line? Does nothing happen and no error code?

Comment: This code does not have any errorits working for other websites @QHarr, but its not working when I am changing the my neviagtion URL to internal link (I think it is an ERP portal form) and also changing my getelementById("bid_manager_name") and assign some value. I have shared the image please take a closer look.

Comment: In the code you sent I don't see an elements with the IDs "USERID" or "USPW"

Comment: you can use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html. That way we can use it for testing.

Comment: I have added the html code and make some changes in vba. But as suggested the navigation URL will not work externally.